# ERROR Campaign not found: NW9D3AFB4C9BDE48C8868B546C9EB9AF12

Tags: dms

I keep seeing `ERROR Campaign not found: NW9D3AFB4C9BDE48C8868B546C9EB9AF12` in the logs on `CD servers` of a `Sitecore 8.2` instance. There are variants with different ID's. There's no stack trace so I don't really know where to begin.

Does anyone know what could be causing this rather frequent issue?

Comment: Someone is calling your site with sc_camp=NW9D3AFB4C9BDE48C8868B546C9EB9AF12. Likely a campaign you had active at one point, which has since been deleted. Campaigns should not be deleted.

Comment: Thank you very much. Would I be correct in thinking there is no way to restore this without access to an old enough backup?

Comment: With a bit of tinkering, you CAN create a new campaign, then serialize/edit id/deserialize the item to force the old ID in place. Then publish that.